# OS X run bash command as another user with sudo privileges

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, root, sudo

I have root access in my terminal and I am trying to run a command as another user with sudo privileges and I can't make it work.

Here is the scenario:

I am logged in as root and I want to execute `sudo echo hello world` as the user `javier`.

I currently have `sudo -u javier sudo echo hello world` but it prompts for a password.

Is there a way of running this without it prompting for a password?

Comment: You do understand that `sudo` runs a command as root? If you're already root, why do you need this?

Comment: In real life, sudo is within a script I did not write and have to control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're a `sudoer`, then you could edit the `/etc/sudoers`
file for the user `javier` using vim :

```
sudo vi /etc/sudoers
```

and add something like :

```
javier ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Save the file and then execute your command. You should be good to go.

Comment: Can you please explain what this does and how it works?

Comment: @JavierCarmona: The `NOPASSWD:ALL` is all what we are interested in.  It just means allow the user `javier` to use  `sudo` for all commands without a password.

Comment: You may be aware of the fact that commands may be grouped in the sudoers file using the `Cmnd_Alias` feature and this way you can disable `sudo` password for select commands. See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246455/how-to-give-nopasswd-access-to-multiple-commands-via-sudoers) question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:
sudo -u javier -i echo "hello world"

Or try
sudo -u javier -i ls -al

So that root runs the command in user context.